# Can you switch tenses like this mid sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, american-english, sequence-of-tenses

> Ray was fluent in American sign language, signing as fluently as he speaks.

Does this sentence make any grammatical sense? Does it need fixing? Is it appropriate to use in a formal setting? Thank you in advance.

Comment: I would not change the tense.  "Ray is fluent......as he speaks" or "Ray was fluent....as he spoke".

Answer (score 0):

You could use this at a formal commemorative service in giving a **spoken eulogy** for Ray.  The uncertainty in tense conveys part of the confusion one feels in describing a loved one who has recently passed.

It's not "grammatically correct", but because the listeners have a prior knowledge of the grammar, and expectations of the speaker and the occasion, breaking the rules can say things beyond the words themselves, so long as the speech is "in the moment" and not contrived in advance.

In a *written* eulogy it would be inappropriate to the point of insulting, since one of the ways we show respect is by "doing things right". Most other formal situations would work the same way.